# Grouping tags based on a specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-group

A text snippet like

> 04040p0015 Macro drive object / Macro DO SERVO, VECTOR,  HLA, SERVO_AC,  VECTOR_AC,  SERVO_I_AC,  VECTOR_I_AC,  A_INF, S_INF, R_INF,  B_INF, TM31,  TM15DI_DO, TM120,  TM150,

has to be parsed into the four groups

1. 04040
2. p0015
3. Macro drive object / Macro DO
4. SERVO, VECTOR,  HLA, SERVO_AC,  VECTOR_AC,  SERVO_I_AC,  VECTOR_I_AC,  A_INF, S_INF,
   R_INF,  B_INF, TM31,  TM15DI_DO, TM120,  TM150,

Where the first and second groups represent different kind of IDs, the 3rd group represents a title and the 4th group contains tags, consisting of 2 or more capital letters, followed by none or one _ , followed by none or more capital letters, followed by a comma.

[The regex](https://regexr.com/7lv07)

```
([0-9]+)([rp][0-9]{4,})(.*)([A-Z]{2,}_?[A-Z,0-9]{2,},)
```

returns

1. 04040
2. p0015
3. Macro drive object / Macro DO SERVO, VECTOR,  HLA, SERVO_AC,  VECTOR_AC,  SERVO_I_AC,
   VECTOR_I_AC,  A_INF, S_INF, R_INF,  B_INF, TM31,  TM15DI_DO, TM120,
4. TM150,

i.e., it gets the first two groups right, but fails to correctly separate the last two groups.

What is wrong with the regex expression?

Comment: Ae "tags" always single words?

Comment: Yes. I have specified the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to get desired 4 capture groups:

```bash
(\d+)([rp]\d{4,})(.*?)\s+((?:[A-Z]\w+,\s+)+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tsriRK/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\d+)`: 1st group to capture 1+ digits
- `([rp]\d{4,})`: 2nd group to match text starting with `r` or `p` followed by 4+ digits
- `(.*?)`: 3rd group to match and capture 0 or more of any characters (lazy)
- `\s+`: 1+ whitespaces
- `((?:[A-Z]\w+,\s+)+)`: 4th group to match & capture words starting with upper case letter and followed by comma and 1+ whitespaces

Comment: You can just use: `(\d+)([rp]\d{4,5}(?:\[0\.{3}[n,\d]+\])?)(.*?)\s+((?:[A-Z,0-9,_]+,?\s+)+)(.*)`